# UIImageView /UIImage Not Working - What Am I Doing Wrong?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage

I am not getting my image working.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

`musclePicture` is a string in format of `picture.png`

1st view:

```
NSString *muscleURL = [[self.muscleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"musclePicture"];
specificExerciseTableViewController.muscleImage = [UIImage imageNamed:muscleURL];
```

2nd view:

```
detailViewController.muscleImage = self.muscleImage;
```

3rd view:

```
self.image = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:muscleImage];
[image release];
```

Edit:

```
MusclesTableViewController.m
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *muscleURL = [[self.muscleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"musclePicture"];
    specificExerciseTableViewController.muscleImage = [UIImage imageNamed:muscleURL]; 
}

SpecificExerciseTableViewController.h
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *muscleImage;

SpecificExerciseTableViewController.m
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    detailViewController.muscleImage = self.muscleImage;
}

DetailViewController.h
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *muscleImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;

DetailViewController.m
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.image.image = muscleImage;
}
```

Comment: IS muscleURL  Local File URL?   1st ,2nd and 3rd are in three diff controller?

Comment: Is "muscleURL" actually a URL, or is it the name of an embedded image resource?

Comment: `muscle URL` is just a string which is is like `bicep.png`.  And yes all 3 are different views.

Comment: is this images are stored in side the bundle?  i mean in the resource folder

Comment: Yes it is.  It is in a plist.  When I NSLog `msucleURL`, it is correct.

Comment: you need to check the log for "specificExerciseTableViewController.muscleImage"   what is the result?

Comment: I get `muscleImage: <UIImage: 0x156450>`

Comment: are you getting the value for self.image as NULL?                    1st ,2nd and 3rd are in three diff Viewcontroller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by giving a frame to your UIImageView after:

```
self.image = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:muscleImage];
[image setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,50,50)];
[image release];
```

Comment: Do I have to do the setFrame?  `imageView` is connect to it's object in IB.  I've done this before without using setFrame, for some reason it is not working this time.

Comment: If you have the imageView through IB why are you allocating it?

Comment: If you have the view in IB you just have to assign the properties. [image setImage:muscleImage]; and don't release it. Also, don't do this in your initWithNibName method. Do that in the viewDidLoad.

Comment: Ok ill get rid of the alloc.  How do I assign the property?

Comment: If your IB connections are well done, you don't have to instantiate the object in your code.

Comment: Yes, I know that now.  But how do I assign the property?

Comment: In your view controller declare a property like this: @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView; Then you should see in the VC item by right clicking the properties you can assign and imageView should be visible to connect. Do you have any connection in your IB? is the IB file a view or a viewcontroller? There are several ways to implement Xibs and connections. It is hard to tell you exactly what you need without waching the file.

Comment: Everything is already setup in IB.  I just need to assign my image to the imageView.

Comment: Then you just need [image setImage:muscleImage]; But don't do this in the initWithNibName method.

Comment: That works with setting the image but now its crashing and giving me this error: `*** -[CALayer retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x116ac0`

Comment: Have you delete the [image release];

Comment: I never alloc the image in `viewDidLoad`, I just have `[image setImage: muscleImage];`.  I have `[image release];` in dealloc though.

Comment: specificExerciseTableViewController.muscleImage = [UIImage imageNamed:muscleURL]; UIImage returns autorealeased objects. Is muscleImage set as a retain property?

Comment: The property for `specificExerciseTableViewController.muscleImage` is `@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *muscleImage;`

Comment: Can you try [specificExerciseTableViewController setMuscleImage:[UIImage imageNamed:muscleURL]]; ?

Comment: Can you post the line the debugger is stopping? I don't think that the image is the problem now.

Comment: `int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);` in main.m

Comment: Usually in the debugger you have some lines grayed. If you scroll the items you will see that some lines are not grayed. Post the first one that is in black font.

Comment: main is the only one thats black.  When I remove `[image setImage: muscleImage];`, there is no crash though.

Comment: Try to hardcode the image [image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bicep.png"]]; (I guess you have the bicep.png added to your project). If you still have problems, review the way you are declaring the imageview. It seems an overrelasing problem.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you just show me the proper way to setup a UIImageView using UIImage.  I may be doing something wrong with alloc the UIImage or something.

Comment: To help you i need to see the project. If you can send it to me I will take a look. I you can't it will be very hard to explain. It will be as a tutorial and i don't have too much time to write a long explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add image as `subView` to your view.

like this

```
[self.view addSubView:image];
```

or you are having a class variable that is connected to `.xib` file as an `IBOutlet` and you are reinitializing it using `alloc` and `init`, if that is the case then you have to do

```
self.image.image = [UIImage imageNamed: muscleImage];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet:

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[animal imageURL]]];
UIImage *animalImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
```

Assign it your `UIImageView` or `UIImage`.